# How can I optimize my nth order derivative program for all orders?

Tags: python, python-2.7, scientific-computing, numerical-analysis, differentiation

I am trying to write a program to print the nth order derivative of any function. The approach I am using is calculating the coefficients of a Lagrange polynomial of the function by inverting the Vandermonde matrix, and then differentiating the polynomial(which is easier than differentiating the original function,as i am dealing only with the coefficients and using the formula for derivative of x^n).

But, for different functions and for different order derivatives, I have to change h, and the order of the interpolating polynomial; otherwise it becomes numerically unstable. Generally for simple functions (as sin,cos,tan,exp.etc) step size of 0.1 till 11th order derivative,and of 1 till 20th order derivative combined with a n1=2*(order of derivative)+1,gives tolerable results.How can i optimize the value of h,and n1 for all functions and for derivatives of all order?

(Use of eval though not liked by most people,is done here,so that the input function can be given as input).

```
f=raw_input("Enter the function:")
n=input("enter the order of derivative:")
a=input("enter the value at which the derivative is to be found:")
n1=input("enter the number of points by which u want to find the derivative:")
h=0.1#stepsize
N=(n1-1)//2

X=[]#x values
x=a-N*h
while round(x,2)<=a+N*h:
    X.append(x)
    x+=h

Y=[]#y values
for elem in X:
    x=elem
    Y.append(eval(f))

def v(x):#returns vandermonde matrix
    X1=[[0.0 for i in range(len(x))]for j in range(len(x))]
    for i in range(0,len(x)):
        for j in range(0,len(x)):
            X1[i][j]=(x[i]**j)
    return X1

from scipy.linalg import solve

def deriv(c,n):#returns derivative of a polynomial
    for i in range(n):
        b=[]
        for j in range(0,len(c)):
            b.append(c[j]*j)
        del b[0]
        if b==[]:
            break
        else:
            c=b
    if b!=[]:
        return b
    else:
        return [0]

def eve(n):#evaluates the polynomial at that point
    sum=0
    for i in range(0,len(deriv(solve(v(X),Y),n))):#solve(v(X),Y) gives the coefficients of the lagrange polynomial
        sum+=(a**i)*deriv(solve(v(X),Y),n)[i]
    return sum

print eve(n)
```

It is preferable that direct usage of packages like scipy sympy or numpy is minimal.

Comment: I would take a look at Numerical Recipes, Sec. 5.7 on p.229 (http://apps.nrbook.com/empanel/index.html#). There is a nice write-up on numerically computing derivatives. It's a different approach than yours though.